# Moving average of 4 rows of data.table with multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, moving-average

I have a data.table `xSet` with multiple columns. I need a new table with a moving 4 row average for each column individually.

[image: Example input output Table]

Comment: Please don't post images of data. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for better alternatives.

Comment: Please, can you double check your definition of rolling window computation? It does not match neither the "center" nor the "right" window alignment options.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rollapplyr` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(New = rollapplyr(., FUN = mean, width = 4, partial = TRUE)))
```

---

Or similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, paste0("New", names(df1)) := lapply(.SD, 
     function(x) rollapplyr(x, FUN = mean, width = 4, partial = TRUE))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 3 * 15, replace = TRUE),
       ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("Col", 1:3))))
```

Comment: Note that the data.table solution could also be written: `DT[, cbind(.SD, New = rollapplyr(.SD, 4, mean, partial = TRUE))]` where `DT` is the input data.table.

Answer (score 1):

The answers by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51413176/3817004) and [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413077/moving-average-of-4-rows-of-data-table-with-multiple-columns#comment89837697_51413176) call the `rollapplr()` function which uses a right aligned window by default.

But this is in contrast to the definition the OP has shown in the image.

This can be visualised by creating some suitable input data and by using `toString()` instead of `mean()` as aggregation function:

```
library(data.table)
# create suitable input data
DT <- data.table(col1 = 1:15, col2 = 21:35, col3 = 41:55)

DT[, cbind(.SD, New = zoo::rollapplyr(.SD, 4, toString, partial = TRUE))]
```

> ```
>     col1 col2 col3       New.col1       New.col2       New.col3
>  1:    1   21   41              1             21             41
>  2:    2   22   42           1, 2         21, 22         41, 42
>  3:    3   23   43        1, 2, 3     21, 22, 23     41, 42, 43
>  4:    4   24   44     1, 2, 3, 4 21, 22, 23, 24 41, 42, 43, 44
>  5:    5   25   45     2, 3, 4, 5 22, 23, 24, 25 42, 43, 44, 45
>  6:    6   26   46     3, 4, 5, 6 23, 24, 25, 26 43, 44, 45, 46
>  7:    7   27   47     4, 5, 6, 7 24, 25, 26, 27 44, 45, 46, 47
>  8:    8   28   48     5, 6, 7, 8 25, 26, 27, 28 45, 46, 47, 48
>  9:    9   29   49     6, 7, 8, 9 26, 27, 28, 29 46, 47, 48, 49
> 10:   10   30   50    7, 8, 9, 10 27, 28, 29, 30 47, 48, 49, 50
> 11:   11   31   51   8, 9, 10, 11 28, 29, 30, 31 48, 49, 50, 51
> 12:   12   32   52  9, 10, 11, 12 29, 30, 31, 32 49, 50, 51, 52
> 13:   13   33   53 10, 11, 12, 13 30, 31, 32, 33 50, 51, 52, 53
> 14:   14   34   54 11, 12, 13, 14 31, 32, 33, 34 51, 52, 53, 54
> 15:   15   35   55 12, 13, 14, 15 32, 33, 34, 35 52, 53, 54, 55
> ```

`col1` is equal to the row numbers, `New.col1` shows the row indices which are being involved in computing `rollapplyr()`.

Compared to OP's image, only rows 1 and 2 do match. Apparently, a right aligned window does not meet OP's definition.

We can compare OP's requirement with the other alignment options for rolling windows:

```
DT <- data.table(col1 = 1:15, col2 = 21:35, col3 = 41:55)
align_window <- c("center", "left", "right")
DT[, (align_window) := lapply(align_window, 
                              function(x) zoo::rollapply(
                                col1, 4, toString, partial = TRUE, align = x))]
# add OP's definition from image
DT[1:2, OP := right][3, OP := toString(2:4)][4:15, OP := center][]
```

> ```
>     col1 col2 col3         center           left          right             OP
>  1:    1   21   41        1, 2, 3     1, 2, 3, 4              1              1
>  2:    2   22   42     1, 2, 3, 4     2, 3, 4, 5           1, 2           1, 2
>  3:    3   23   43     2, 3, 4, 5     3, 4, 5, 6        1, 2, 3        2, 3, 4
>  4:    4   24   44     3, 4, 5, 6     4, 5, 6, 7     1, 2, 3, 4     3, 4, 5, 6
>  5:    5   25   45     4, 5, 6, 7     5, 6, 7, 8     2, 3, 4, 5     4, 5, 6, 7
>  6:    6   26   46     5, 6, 7, 8     6, 7, 8, 9     3, 4, 5, 6     5, 6, 7, 8
>  7:    7   27   47     6, 7, 8, 9    7, 8, 9, 10     4, 5, 6, 7     6, 7, 8, 9
>  8:    8   28   48    7, 8, 9, 10   8, 9, 10, 11     5, 6, 7, 8    7, 8, 9, 10
>  9:    9   29   49   8, 9, 10, 11  9, 10, 11, 12     6, 7, 8, 9   8, 9, 10, 11
> 10:   10   30   50  9, 10, 11, 12 10, 11, 12, 13    7, 8, 9, 10  9, 10, 11, 12
> 11:   11   31   51 10, 11, 12, 13 11, 12, 13, 14   8, 9, 10, 11 10, 11, 12, 13
> 12:   12   32   52 11, 12, 13, 14 12, 13, 14, 15  9, 10, 11, 12 11, 12, 13, 14
> 13:   13   33   53 12, 13, 14, 15     13, 14, 15 10, 11, 12, 13 12, 13, 14, 15
> 14:   14   34   54     13, 14, 15         14, 15 11, 12, 13, 14     13, 14, 15
> 15:   15   35   55         14, 15             15 12, 13, 14, 15         14, 15
> ```

None of the alignment options does *completely* meet OP's definition. "center" is the best match except for the first 3 rows.

Comment: The pattern in the question seems strange but to replicate it anyways with a single rollapply define the offsets like this:  `offsets <- lapply(pmax(2, 1:15), function(k) head(seq(-1, 2), k)); rollapply(1:15, offsets, toString, partial = TRUE)`